# Get method in rest api

Tags: rest, get

In this article
https://spring.io/understanding/REST
Was said that get method use for retrieving information, but when we use get in method attribute of form in html it is for sending data to the server
plz explain

Answer (score 0):

If you put an url to your rest service into the browser it will use **GET**. The parameters should be put behind **?** separated by **&** `http://example.com?paramA=123&paramB=Hi`.

Or with curl simply: 
`curl -X GET 'http://www.example.com?paramA=123&paramB=Hi'`

if you want to use form you should use it like this:

```
<form action="http://www.example.com">
  <input type="hidden" name="paramA" value="123" /> 
  <input type="hidden" name="paramB" value="Hi" /> 
  <input type="submit" /> 
</form>
```

Comment: The default HTTP method for forms is GET, it is not needed.

Comment: Thanks, I know what is get but i want to know what the meaning of retrieving data at rest according to the article

Comment: Retrieving data - mean that when you request for some data. The rest service will response with data in a plain text, JSON etc. GET is for getting(retrieving data) isn't it self explanatory

Comment: tnx but when we use get in form we send data to server not getting data